# _OBJC_IVAR_$_Answer.answer"

Tags: objective-c, linker-errors

I have a class that holds number ivars:

```
//  Answer.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Answer : NSObject{
    @public
    int firstNumber;
    int secondNumber;
    char myOperator;
}

@end
```

I try to access the code here

```
    numberGroup->firstNumber = arc4random() % 1;
    numberGroup->secondNumber = arc4random() % 10;
    numberGroup->myOperator = arc4random() % 4;
```

and I get this error:

> Ld
>   /Users/jack/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PowerBuilders-emehzkfcgntrhofxhvurovjmnugn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PowerBuilders.app/PowerBuilders
>   normal i386
>       cd "/Users/jack/Desktop/Xcode/Assorted Apps/PowerBuilders"
>       setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/jack/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PowerBuilders-emehzkfcgntrhofxhvurovjmnugn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/jack/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PowerBuilders-emehzkfcgntrhofxhvurovjmnugn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -filelist /Users/jack/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PowerBuilders-emehzkfcgntrhofxhvurovjmnugn/Build/Intermediates/PowerBuilders.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PowerBuilders.build/Objects-normal/i386/PowerBuilders.LinkFileList
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o
>   /Users/jack/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PowerBuilders-emehzkfcgntrhofxhvurovjmnugn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PowerBuilders.app/PowerBuilders
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_IVAR_$_Answer.firstNumber", referenced from:
>         -[ViewController lesson1] in ViewController.o   "_OBJC_IVAR_$_Answer.myOperator", referenced from:
>         -[ViewController lesson1] in ViewController.o   "_OBJC_IVAR_$_Answer.secondNumber", referenced from:
>         -[ViewController lesson1] in ViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You realize that `a4r()%1` will always be 0, right?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: Yes, I have tried cleaning the project, but did not catch the second. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler generates symbol `_OBJC_IVAR_$_Answer.firstNumber` in the data segment as part of the `Answer` class metadata when it processes the `@implementation` section for the `Answer` class.  The data at that symbol is the offset of the `firstNumber` instance variable within an `Answer` object.

Either you aren't linking your app with a file that contains an `@implementation Answer` section, or the compiler hasn't seen the declaration of the `firstNumber` instance variable before it sees the `@implementation Answer` section.  Check that these are all true:

- `Answer.m` is included in your target's Compile Sources phase.
- `Answer.m` contains an `@implementation Answer` section.
- `Answer.m` imports `Answer.h` at the top of `Answer.m`.

Comment: Where is the compile sources phase located? Is it in the scheme editor?

Comment: Click on your project file in the Project Navigator.  Then click on your target in the targets list.  Then click on the Build Phases tab.